# Convert seconds to hours:minutes using "Convert Date" and Robotframework

Tags: python, datetime, robotframework

How to convert seconds to hours:minutes using "Convert Date" with Robotframework

Example:

```
${hours_minutes}=    Convert Date    ${28800.0}    result_format=%H:%M
Log To Console    ${hours_minutes}
```

Output: **09:00**

Expected: **08:00**

The problem is that the above example is using the local time zone. (+1:00)

Is there a way to force using UTC?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to force using UTC?

According to the documentation, no, there is not.

The DateTime library is for formatting dates and times. You don't have a date or a time, you have an interval.

You can write a keyword to do the math yourself. Take the number and do an integer division by 3600 (60 seconds in a minute times 60 minutes in an hour) for hours, and then do modulo 3600 to get minutes.

For example:

```
*** Variables ***
${seconds}  ${28800}

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${time}  evaluate  f"{${seconds//3600}:02d}:{${seconds%3600}:02d}"
    Should be equal as strings  ${time}  08:00
```

Comment: In the meantime, I've already found a solution.
    
    ${time}=    Convert Time    ${28800}    timer
    ${hours_minutes}=    Get Substring    ${time}    0    5
 
I like your solution, it doesn't require an additional library. Thx.
Btw, the value can also be seen as a Unix timestamp, so I wonder how to convert 
a timestamp into a valid UTC date.